# float for list element vs other elements

Tags: html, css

```css
nav > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#one {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      he has a cow
    </li>
    <li >
      he has a dog
    </li>
    <li>
      he has a mouse
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="main">
  <div id="one">
    <br/>he has a one</div>
  <div id="two">he has a two</div>
  <div id="three">he has a three</div>
</div>
```

Now my question is why all listed three items float though I just want the first listed item to be floated. And why `div` elements not behaving like listed items.

Comment: Then I suggest you do some additional reading one classes and IDs and the way `float` affects elements.

Comment: extremely sorry sir.... i have edited the code .... now pls check

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is why all listed three items `float` though I just want
>   the first listed item to be floated. And why `div` elements not behaving
>   like listed items.

There is a [difference between class `.` and ID `#`.](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

So you are floating **all** the list items by using:

```
nav > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
```

If you want to just apply the first item you apply it the first class `.one`.

see snippet below:

#### Snippet

```css
.one {
  float: left;
}
li {
/*demo*/
  width: 100px;
  
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="one">
      he has a cow
    </li>
    <li class="one">
      he has a dog
    </li>
    <li>
      he has a mouse
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="main">
  <div id="one">
    <br/>he has a one</div>
  <div id="two">he has a two</div>
  <div id="three">he has a three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with :

```
nav ul li:first-child {
 float:left;
}
```

by `nav >ul >li` you are selecting all `li`'s that are direct child of the `ul` element

Answer (score 0):

Alessio,

The ">" selector applies to all items directly below the selected item in the `DOM` hierarchy.
In this case `nav > ul > li` applies to all of the list elements which are direct children of nav > ul.
The selector which applies only to the first element of a series would be

```
nav > ul > li:nth-child(1) {
  float: left
}
```